# playframework ProtocolException invalid message

Tags: playframework, protocolexception

I have a funny phenomenon:

If I start a blank index.html page with this controller:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void index() {
        render();
    }
}
```

I don't see the index page but get the offer to download a file with this content:

```
FHcodeProtocolExceptionmessageinvalid message tagZ
```

What is the magic here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the HTTP port in your application.conf (default is set to
9000).

Comment: I tried it a bit later with the same port (9000) and it worked again. Maybe the Play! people can tell. But thanks and regards anyway. Eriq