# Error in character encoding in "Hello World" application of Play Framework 2.0

Tags: character-encoding, playframework

I'm learning about Play Framework. So I decided to start with this [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/firstapp). After creating the first application and trying to see it in localhost:9000. I receive an error.

In Google Chrome when I try to open the page, the tab closes immediatly and downloads a file with the next content:

- FHcodeProtocolExceptionmessageinvalid message tagZ

Internet Explorer doesn't close but shows me the same message. In Firefox I get the same error.

I've tried changing the encoding in Firefox but nothing happens. If instead of Windows, I use Ubuntu the problem doesn't happen

I'm using:

- Play framework 2.0
- Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
- Google Chrome 19.0.1068 dev-m
- Firefox 11
- Internet Explorer 9

I haven't moodified any file yet. I only have used the commands in the tutorial:

```
~$ play new helloworld
~$ cd helloworld
~$ play run
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You say you're using Play Framework 2.0, but you tutorial links to 1.2.4 ... maybe that's the problem? Otherwise I don't know, I haven't used Play 2.0 yet.

Comment: I don't think so. The tutorial is what they have :) and I don't think those commands changed from version 1.2.4 to 2.0.  I guess it has something to do with Windows, but I couldn't find what :(

Comment: Hi maartencls! Please check my comment to Marek Sybilak. His advice is like yours. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I really don't know but apparently changing the port number and making sure the template isn't empty can solve this issue. Look at: [thread on play framework forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/BS2_HiBmSzU) and [someone else with this error on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823743/playframework-protocolexception-invalid-message)

Comment: Now it's working, but the next time I'll try that. Thanks and regards! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the new tutorial:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTodoList

Play 2.0 is different than 1.2.4 and it is probably the main reason you got errors.
There is a different way you build apps.

If you want to use activator with play framework then check this out -

https://quintupledev.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/play-framework-intro-hello-world/

Comment: I don't know what happened. I follow your link and the only difference I noted was that they don't enter into the directory as I did. I also tried the two forms of building apps (the one from the older tutuorial and the one from the newer) and they both worked.